# java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source) Error

Tags: java, stack, peek

I'm using Java Stack as follows:

```
Stack<Integer> stack_y = new Stack<Integer>();
```

And later at some point I'm using push, peek, and pop:

```
stack_y.push(1);   
//some code
peek_value=stack_y.peek();
//some code   
pop=stack_y.pop();
```

While `push` is working fine, I get following error for `pop` and `peek`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source)
    at Hw1Node.DFS(Hw1Node.java:246)
```

Also it gives an error in the main function at the line where I call the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [`EmptyStackException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html) information you see that is 'Thrown by methods in the `Stack` class to indicate that the stack is empty'.

So you are trying to make a `.pop()` or a `peek()` when the stack is empty. Remember that you can only make one `pop()` for each `push()` you have done previously.